# How to test likelihood hypothesis on dataset?

Tags: python, probability, data-analysis, hypothesis-testing

How to test the following hypothesis?
**The larger the fare the more likely the customer is to be travailing alone.**

Using the data below, how would one be able to test the hypothesis?

```
import seaborn as sns

# dataset
df= sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df[['fare','alone']].head()

    fare    alone
0   7.2500  False
1   71.2833 False
2   7.9250  True
3   53.1000 False
4   8.0500  True
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
#subset for alone = True
alone = df['fare'].loc[df['alone'] == True]

#import Wilcoxon test
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon  

#run wilcoxon test
wilcoxon(alone, not_alone)

> WilcoxonResult(statistic=10173.0, pvalue=2.8669052202786427e-28)
```

Comment: You could perform a logistic regression using the `alone` variable as the dependent variable and the `fare` variable as the independent variable. This will allow you to see how strong the relationship is and if it is statistically significant.

Comment: try a permutation test

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question that is posted as a comment says to try a logistic regression of "alone/multiple" on the fare. This might be a good first thought, but it suffers from a few issues.

1. Unless you are careful (more careful than many would be), you allow your analysis to check for the opposite relationship: that larger fairs are associated with less probability of the traveler being alone.
2. It tests a strictly linear (in log-odds) relationship.
3. Standard methods to allow GLMs to model nonlinearity, such as splines, need not require the relationship to be monotonically increasing, so your model could show a decreasing trend in a region.

(I might argue that it is worth exploring if there is a region where increasing fare results in a lower probability of traveling alone, but that isn't your question.)

I would argue for a one-sided Wilcoxon test to see if people traveling alone tend to have higher fares, which is logically equivalent to your question.

A Wilcoxon test removes the issues related to a strictly linear relationship (just a linear shift), and it is easy to do the one-sided test. If you would use Spearman correlation to explore a similar question but with a continuous or ordinal variable instead of your alone/multiple variable, then Wilcoxon is a perfect fit, as both Wilcoxon the Spearman correlation are special cases of the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model.

Comment: please refer to update portion of post. The Wilcoxon test recommended provides pvalue given a null hypothesis, however I'm having trouble interpreting the results in terms of larger vs smaller fare.

Comment: @IOIOIOIOIOIOI You need to run the test as one-sided. Check the SciPy documentation for how to do that. // For the interpretation, write out (literally) the null and alternative hypotheses. If you reject the null in favor of the alternative, what does that mean?